# Could I migrate a vscode extension from an existent publisher to a new publisher?

Tags: node.js, azure, visual-studio-code, devops

I forgot my user once and I created another account, so now I have access to both accounts but now for me, it's better to use only one and I want to maintain the number of downloads and metrics